# How to add a manual deploy to prod step to CodeStar (Lambda + Express)

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-code-deploy, aws-codepipeline, aws-codestar

I'm using the Node.js Express template with AWS Lambda in CodeStar and it all works really well, perfect for my use case, other than I can't seem to stop it from deploying both the staging and production environments with each and every commit of code.

Ideally I'd like it to push all commits to staging and then a manual push to production once the QA team have had a chance to take a look at it.

Now I've taken a look at the underlying structure, and I can see that in API Gateway there are two stages configured, prod and stage, and I can use these to set stage variables at least (though I'm not sure how to access them at present... more reading required!).

But in Lambda I can only see the one function, and it's the "newest" version, so I can't really figure out how to do what I need...?

Comment: Thanks for your interest. We are not exactly sure which two environments you are referring to. If the staging and production environments you mentioned are two CodePipeline stages, then the answer from @TimB would definitely work. Thanks @TimB! If what you meant were the Stage and Prod stages displayed on the API gateway stages page, then currently CodeStar doesn't support deploying to them one by one. Lambda deployments to the stages under API gateway are done together. I have passed your concerns to the team for further review and consideration. Your feedback is very much appreciated and you

Comment: Hi @JingZhu, I wonder if there has been any change / update to this issue. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you go to the AWS CodePipeline console you should find a pipeline associated with your CodeStar project. You can edit this pipeline from the CodePipeline console to add a [manual approval action](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/codepipeline/latest/userguide/approvals.html).

By placing the manual approval action after staging but before production you will have the opportunity to run a manual QA process before you approve the change for production.